# JDOM Add new child to a specific element on an exesting XML

Tags: java, jdom

I'm new with JDOM my question is how can I add child to an specific element for example:

```
 <component>
   <extension point="shema">
     <shema name="1">
     <shema name="2">
   </extension>
   <extension point="doctyp">
     <doctyp name="1">
     <doctyp name="2">
   </extension>
</component>
```

For example how can I add element `shema` in extension that contain only `shemas` as element?

Comment: You have spelt 'schema' and 'doctype' wrong in your example; whether that is a problem or not depends on what you are doing with this document.

Comment: What is your code so far? Can you post it?